# Search in Play Market with localized Application name

Tags: android, localization, google-play, apk

We uploaded the application with localized Name, Description, Short description e.t.c. for **3 languages**. Also application has localized resources for all **3 languages**.

But in Play Market we can search only with Name on **2 languages**.

What we should do to be able to search with all 3 languages?

**UPDATE:**

Google Play Developer Support registered this problem. Hope they will clarify the issue asap.

Comment: What do you mean by "But in Google Play we can only see the app in 2 languages", do you mean that you cannot find the app in the 3rd language or that incorrect language is displayed in Google Play?

Comment: I mean: "cannot find app". Description of app in 3rd language is correct.

Comment: This sounds like your app may be ranked lower in that particular language though, and there may not be much you can do except maybe doing some keyword optimization.

Comment: Hmm. We didn't have any difference in localization for second language... How we cane check your idea?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the name of your app, so we can check & understand the issue more clearly.

Comment: You can find it using "mobile customs" or "мобильная таможня". Third language is Azerbaijani - "Mobil gömrük" , but this didn't work as I described.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, definitely beyond my ability to help :-/ The best advice I can give is try contacting Google for help, though it should be noted they are not known for quick (or any) response to such inquiries.

Comment: That's, probably, because Google Play does not support Azerbaijani. See https://play.google.com/store?hl=az - it's in Russian, not in Azerbaijani.

Comment: @ozbek I don't think so, you can search with Azerbaijani word "gömrük", and it will find several applications

Comment: @Sasha, those you are seeing has only one text in Azerbaijani for all locales. Those are not translated and localized. Remove English and Russian locales from your application title/description and you will also see yours.

Comment: @ozbek I understand your idea, but it is really impossible in our case... We need to support all three languages

Comment: I am not suggesting to actually remove English and Russian translations. That was to explain why some apps are being seen in Azerbaijani.

Comment: Try to change system language of your device on Azerbaijani and repeat the search.

Comment: @Nikolai Fail, didn't find.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a support issue for Google's Market.

Comment: @BradLarson if you see comments and votes in community opinion it is not offtopic.

Comment: @Sasha: would you edit your question to explain what Google Support said? It might be helpful for a reader in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer yes of course i will add an answer, but did not receive any information yet. They send only suggestion to wait ...

Comment: If you are still waiting since 2nd November, I suspect they need reminding! I've no experience of Google or Android support though...